# "Widget" or "Gadget"?

Tags: widget, semantics

This question is about semantics.

I have a client who says that the term "widget" should only be used when referring to a dynamic object that syndicates your own content on to a third party site. I believe widget can be used to refer to any self-contained dynamic object on a site (your own or a third party). However, my client says that if the object is on your own site, it is a "gadget."

I'm not sure if there is an official definition, but I'm interested to know what is the common understanding of the difference, if any, between the two terms?

Comment: I consider gadgets to be hardware, while widgets are ..

Comment: Umm.  My google gadgets (their term, not mine) are definitely not hardware.

Comment: This is an old question, but I'll chip in my two cents: I see "gadgets" as something with interactivity, like a quiz or poll module; while a "widget" is less interactive, like an RSS/Twitter feed, or other syndicated content. Although there is a bit of a grey area in the middle...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionary.com:

> widg⋅et
>   -noun
>   a small mechanical device, as a knob or switch, esp. one whose name is not known or cannot be recalled; gadget: a row of widgets on the instrument panel.
>
> gadg⋅et
>   -noun
>   a mechanical contrivance or device; any ingenious article.

'Widget' does **not** mean 'Window Gadget'. These terms have existed for 150 years in published literature (~85 for 'widget'), and as far as programming goes, it's up to you.

Comment: You are right that the 'widget' word existed before the computer era, but the GUI widget really means 'window gadget'.  See the wikipedia article.

Answer (score 16):

If your client wants to call it a gadget, let him/her call it a gadget. They have similar meanings, neither is really a very technical term, and it's a waste of time to argue the point.

Answer (score 0):

"Widget" means "Window Gadget"

Personally, I don't really like the term 'widget', especially in GUI libraries.  I'm still waiting for the library that will provide a 'window' namespace with a 'gadget' class declared in it.

Comment: +1 for the etymology, though I was initially skeptical.  I would differentiate between how the word was derived and what it actually means, though.  Nowadays, widget has several different meanings.