# What is the technical (functional) different between a Gadget and a Widget?

Tags: widget, comparison

Already I found this ["Widget" or "Gadget"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620093/widget-or-gadget) related to this question,

But I'm looking really for the technical/ Functional differences between those two.

Answer (score 3):

Go to http://www.google.com/webmasters/gadgets/ and read this:

> Gadgets powered by Google are miniature objects made by Google users
>   like you that offer cool and dynamic content **that can be placed on
>   any page on the web.**

So any gadget like Google Gadgets can be placed on any page on the web